# Button not able to change the variable with onClick method in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a button that will toggle the details of an object. But, when the onClick method is not working and the button is not able to change the value of 'show' variable.

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './hospital.module.css';
import {Animated} from "react-animated-css";
const Hospital = props =>{
    let show = false;
    const togglebeds = () => {
         show = !show;
     }

return (
    <div className={classes.Hospital}>
        <h1 className={classes.Heading}>{props.name}</h1>
        <button className={classes.Show} onClick={togglebeds}>Show Beds</button>
        {show ?
        <Animated animationIn="bounceInLeft" animationOut="fadeOut" isVisible={true}>
        <p className={classes.Bronze}>Bronze Beds Availability : {props.bed1av}</p><p className= 
        {classes.Price}> Price: {props.bedtype1}</p>
        <p className={classes.Silver}>Silver Beds Availability : {props.bed2av}</p><p className= 
        {classes.Price}> Price: {props.bedtype2}</p>
        <p className={classes.Gold}>Gold Beds Availability : {props.bed3av}</p><p className= 
        {classes.Price}>   Price: {props.bedtype3}</p>
        </Animated> : null}
    </div>
);
}

export default Hospital;
```

Comment: By the way is there a reason you add conditional rendering? `{show ? <Animated>...</Animated> : null }`. I think you can achieve the same thing by passing `isVisible={show}` prop to `Animated` component.

Answer (score 3):

React components re-render only if you update their state (or if their props changed). You can keep `show` in a local state variable so you can see the changes.

```
const Hospital = props => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  const togglebeds = () => {
    setShow(prevShow => !prevShow); // or setShow(!show);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use state to change `show` value

```
const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
const togglebeds = () => {
  setShow(!show)
};
```